# Problems delaying the execution of a code in Android

Tags: android, multithreading, wait, i2c

I have implemented an app which can communicates with a metawear device through i2c communication. The problem I have right now is that after sending a write command I need to wait a certain amount of time until I read the values (around 150ms).

The problem I have is that it doesn't wait that specific time. I used TimeUnit, Thread.sleep and wait functions but still doesn't make the delay I want it to execute the next line of code. Here is the function that I have implemented:

```
  @Override
  protected void test_application(){

    timerModule.scheduleTask(new Timer.Task() {

        @Override
        public void commands() {

            i2cModule.writeData((byte) 0x34, (byte) 0xA0, new byte[]{(byte) 0x98});

            //We need to wait >80ms for the ADC to finish the conversion value
           // synchronized (this) {
            //    try {
            //        wait(150);
            //    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            //        e.printStackTrace();
           //     }
            //}

            try{
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(150);
            } catch (InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            //try{
            //   Thread.currentThread().sleep(150);
            //} catch (InterruptedException e){
            //    e.printStackTrace();
            //};

            //After waiting 150ms for the conversion time, we read the output value through the I2C line
            i2cModule.readData((byte)0x34, (byte)0x00, (byte)4).onComplete(new CompletionHandler<byte[]>() {
                @Override
                public void success(byte[] result) {
                    auxvar = result;

                }
            });

            finalvoltage = ((auxvar[0]&0x3F)<<18)|(auxvar[1]<<10)|(auxvar[2]<<2)|((auxvar[3]&0xC0));
            diff_volt1 = (float)finalvoltage * 3/16777215;

            LineData data = chart.getData();

            if (startTime == -1) {
                data.addXValue("0");
                startTime= System.currentTimeMillis();
            } else {
                data.addXValue(String.format("%.2f", (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000.f));
            }
            data.addEntry(new Entry(diff_volt1, sampleCount), 0);

            sampleCount++;

        }


    }, 500, false).onComplete(new AsyncOperation.CompletionHandler<Timer.Controller>() {
        @Override
        public void success(Timer.Controller result) {
            result.start();
        }
    });
```

I want it to wait before executing the `i2cmodule.readData()` function. Here is the capture from the logic analyzer so that you could see that it doesn't wait before reading the data

[image]

Does anyone know how to implement this or solve this issue? Thanks anyway.

EDIT: I have changed the writing command to just one line and the new output of the logic analyzer is as follows:

```
byte[] hello = {(byte)0xA0, (byte)0x98};

i2cModule.writeData((byte) 0x34, (byte) 0x00, hello);
```

And the new output is at follows:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried polling?

Comment: Where are this function from? They might block or not and then your timing is wrong.

Comment: Hi Shark. What do you mean by polling? I don't know what is that. Sorry

Comment: Hi Radu. What do you mean by where it is from? You mean in which file java file is located? Sorry for the inconvinience

Comment: Have you tried measuring the delta between the time before the call to sleep() and the time after the call to sleep()? I don't see any obvious reason Thread.sleep() wouldn't block there.

Answer (score 0):

Generally it is a bad idea to 'wait' for a command to finish if it is asynchronous. You need to make sure that the `.writeData()` method is finished BEFORE you execute the `.readData()` method.

There are many ways to do this. I like the listener pattern, but for this you could also use an abstract class construction.

The basic idea is to implement a class (let's call this `DataWriter`) that invokes an abstract method as soon as the writing of the data is done.

A very basic example would be:

*class definition*

```
abstract class DataWriter {
     public DataWriter() {
         doWritingFunction();
     }

     private void doWritingFunction() {
          //here you do your writing operation
          //when it's done it calls:
          onWritingDone();
     }

     abstract void onWritingDone();
 }
```

Then you instantiate your class like this:

```
DataWriter dataWriter = new DataWriter() {

       @Override
       void onWritingDone() {
            //do data read here      
       }

 };
```

**Never use Thread.sleep() to wait for an asynchronous task to finish, since you never know when it is going to be finished**

Comment: Hi Tim. Thanks for your answer. The problem is that it doesn't require too much time to do the writing; the thing is that after writing the data, as I am trying to obtain the output of an ADC, it will require some time it to finish the conversion, that is why I have to wait around 150ms. If not, it will give a NACK as the image shows.

Comment: I don't think writeData() is asynchronous. It looks like it blocks until it finishes the write and returns.

Comment: But readData it is. I need to wait before reading so that the conversion is done. I don't know if I am understanding correctly what you are saying and I apologize for the inconvenience if I cause.

Comment: The first thing to do is measure the time before and after the call to sleep and see if it is actually is around 150ms. If it is, then the problem is not with your code and is somewhere farther down the stream...

Comment: And how do I check the time before and after the sleep function?

Comment: timeBefore = System.currentTimeMillis(); thread.sleep(); timeAfter = System.currentTimeMillis(); delta = timeAfter - timeBefore;

Comment: I have just checked, you are right, the delta is 150ms. But now knowing that, what is the cause of this problem or how to solve this issue? I know from the information given by i2c communication of the metawear, the readData function is Asynchronous. Does this affect to it?

Comment: I would start by setting the delay to a longer period of time, say 1 second, and seeing if that increases the delay on the logic analyzer. The readData() call shouldn't have anything to do with the problem. It is asynchronous so it doesn't block in the case of a long read. I assume right now it isn't reading anything so it just sits there forever because there wasn't enough time between the write and the read.

Comment: I have been modifying it but it doesn't change, still the same output. Any more ideas? Thanks a lot for the help and your time

Comment: Are you certain you are interpreting the output of the logic analyzer correctly? I see a write and what appears to be an incomplete write, but I am not seeing a read. Can you provide a bit more context? I suspect it is actually working, but for whatever reason that isn't apparent.

Comment: I have modified the the data to be written to i2c into just one function. I have put the captures from the logic analyzer. At first it sends correctly but the reading the value is 0 (The first 4 bits aren't used for the conversion value). It also tries to write before it doesn't send any data. But later the program sends to a device address that I haven't put in my code (0xEE/0xEF and 0x52) and I don't know why or how it sends to that address. Any ideas?